# sum values of 2 matrices by matching rowname and colname

Tags: r, matrix, sum, match

I have 2 matrices A and B. I want to add values in both matrices into one by matching colnames and rownames. Matrix A has all possible buckets as rownames and colnames. Matrix B has only few of these. Both colnames and rownames are same. It is like a cross tab. (or confusion matrix)

I want to have final matrix C with all possible rownames and colnames and values added up from A and B.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with some dummy data (Ideally you should provide this) -

```
A <- matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(paste0("A", 1:3), paste0("A", 1:3)))
B <- matrix(2, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(paste0("A", 2:3), paste0("A", 2:3)))

A
   A1 A2 A3
A1  1  1  1
A2  1  1  1
A3  1  1  1

B
   A2 A3
A2  2  2
A3  2  2

A[rownames(B), colnames(B)] <- A[rownames(B), colnames(B)] + B

A
   A1 A2 A3
A1  1  1  1
A2  1  3  3
A3  1  3  3
```